# PHP: Losing characters when concatenating long strings

Tags: php, utf-8, concatenation, character

My application builds a string to send to my customer containing html links in order for them to download their products.

I basically loop through the orders that they have made and generate a string for the `mail()` function.

```
$links .= "<p><a href='http://www.example.com/dl/Downloadpage.php?reference=".$ref."&pass=".$passlink."&pid=".$product['pr_id']."'>Click here to download ".$product['Title']."</a></p>";
```

As soon as there are 5 or more links, I will lose a character in the middle of one of the links... for example `http://ww.mysite.com` <- there is only one "w", or if the reference is `1128098` it will print `112098`.

I could have understood if it was at the end of the string... anyone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code that works with that string? It's much more likely that there's a bug in the code rather than the string concatenation. If you can get us the parts that manipulate it we can hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: No idea if this would help, but what would happen if you pushed all your strings into an array and then implode() it to build the string instead of using concatenation?

Comment: Normally, smtp protocol implementations not allow more than ~76 columns/chars in one line, then the lines are cut during the communication. Try dispose the link one line each (surrounding with "\n").

Comment: Can you write the output of the string to the screen rather than email it? It's possible the characters are being lost when being emailed from PHP.

Comment: please test `$links .= "<p><a href='http://www.mysite.com/dl/Downloadpage.php?reference=".$ref."&pass=".$passlink."&pid=".$product['pr_id']."'>Click here to download ".$product['Title']."</a></p>\r\n";` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone... jprofitt: I am just sending the string out in the php mail() function as the message parameter afterwards. Thanks Gordon, I'll bear that in mind. Paulo, thanks for that code, I will give that a try and see if it works, it certainly seems like something along those lines. Igor, I can't print it to the screen because it is part of a paypal IPN verification that the customer doesn't see.

Comment: Paulo :) Thankyou SO much! Adding the newlines worked :) Thanks everyone else too for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, smtp protocol implementations not allow more than ~76 columns/chars in one line, then the lines are cut during the communication. Try dispose the link one line each (surrounding with "\n").

Please try:
`$links .= "<p><a href='http://www.mysite.com/dl/Downloadpage.php?reference=".$ref."&pass=".$passl‌​ink."&pid=".$product['pr_id']."'>Click here to download ".$product['Title']."</a></p>\r\n";`